# Get CPU utilization stats from C program

Tags: monitoring, cpu, c, top

I want to read the CPU utilization stats from a C program, I am interested in the percentage of use of CPU, *steal time* etc. These stats are shown in the 3rd row from the `top` command.

I tried to parse `top` 's output with `awk` (`top -n 1 -b | awk '{print $0}'`), but it seems that `top` gives always the same 'fictional' values before it starts showing correct stats.

Is there a way from code, or by parsing some command's output to get the CPU utilization stats?

**Edit:**

The platform is Linux

Thank you.

Comment: Sure, but there is no standard way. Precise the target OS(es).

Answer (score 7):

You want to read the first few lines of `/proc/stat`. You'll need to read it twice, a measured time apart, and subtract the first set of numbers from the second. The lines look like this:

```
cpu  1526724 408013 600675 541100340 2861417 528 14531 0 0 0
cpu0 344507 77818 251244 134816146 1119991 324 13283 0 0 0
cpu1 502614 324065 179301 133991407 1631824 136 906 0 0 0
cpu2 299080 3527 79456 136144067 103208 59 255 0 0 0
cpu3 380521 2602 90672 136148719 6393 7 86 0 0 0
intr 2111239193 344878476 16943 ...
```

The first line is aggregate for all cores. The next lines show each core. When you see the line that start with `intr`, you know to stop parsing.

Each number is the amount of time the CPU has spent in a particular state. The units are typically hundredths of a second. The fields are `user`, `nice`, `system`, `idle`, `iowait`, `irq`, `softirq`, `steal`, `guest`, and `guest_nice`.

The authoritative documentation is, of course, the source code. If you have a copy of the Linux kernel source handy, look at `fs/proc/stat.c`, particularly the `show_stat` function.

Comment: Do you know at what frequency the proc/stat is being updated? like once every 1ms or something, thank you.

Comment: They're not real files. Their contents are calculated when you open them.

Answer (score 3):

There is [some example](http://brokestream.com/procstat.html) on the web that shows how to read `/proc/pid/stat` in C.

You could read `utime` or `stime` values at two distinct moments and compute the desired cpu utilization stats. (I guess `top` uses this raw data too.)

(I forgot: this is linux specific.)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using sysinfo below is snippet

```c
#include "sysinfo.h"

getstat(cpu_use,cpu_nic, cpu_sys, cpu_idl, cpu_iow, cpu_xxx, cpu_yyy, cpu_zzz, pgpgin, pgpgout, pswpin, pswpout, intr, ctxt, &running,&blocked, &dummy_1, &dummy_2);

float cpuconsumption = (float) ((   (float) ((*cpu_use) + (*cpu_sys)) / (float)((*cpu_use)+(*cpu_sys)+(*cpu_idl)))*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody wanted some quick cpu usage values directly from top inside a c application, this snippet just opens a pipe, and returns the last line of the top process with the cpu information.

```
/**
 * Get last cpu load as a string (not threadsafe)
 */
static char* getCpuLoadString()
{
    /*
     * Easiest seems to be just to read out a line from top, rather than trying to calc it ourselves through /proc stuff
     */
    static bool started = false;
    static char buffer[1024];
    static char lastfullline[256];
    static int bufdx;
    static FILE *fp;

    if(!started) {
        /* Start the top command */

        /* Open the command for reading. */
        fp = popen("top -b  -d1", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
          printf("Failed to run top command for profiling\n" );
          exit(1);
        }

        /* Make nonblocking */
        int flags;
        flags = fcntl(fileno(fp), F_GETFL, 0);
        flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
        fcntl(fileno(fp), F_SETFL, flags);

        started = true;
    }


    /*
     * Read out the latest info, and remember the last full line
     */
    while( fgets (buffer + bufdx, sizeof(buffer) - bufdx, fp)!=NULL ) {
        /* New data came in. Iteratively shift everything until a newline into the last full line */
        char *newlinep;
        while((newlinep = strstr(buffer, "\n"))) {
            int shiftsize = (newlinep - buffer + 1);
            *newlinep = 0; /* Nullterminate it for strcpy and strstr */
            /* Check if the line contained "cpu" */
            if(strstr(buffer, "Cpu")) {
                strncpy(lastfullline, buffer, sizeof(lastfullline) - 1); /* Copy full line if it contained cpu info */
            }
            memmove(buffer, buffer + shiftsize, shiftsize); /* Shift left (and discard) the line we just consumed */
        }
    }

    /*
     * Return the last line we processed as valid output
     */
    return lastfullline;
}
```

I then simply call `printf(" %s\n", getCpuLoadString());` every second