# getting %CPU value from top for all cores in a system

Tags: top, cpu-usage

I have a 4 socket server having 24 core cpu's.  96 cores total.  How can I, in RHEL 7/8 Linux, get the value that is `%CPU` as shown by `top` for every core in the system?

*I plan on writing C code that will periodically gather all these numbers to calculate a system utilization value.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `procfs` mounted at `/proc`, then the first line of `/proc/stat` has the summary for the system, and the next **N** lines have the values for each CPU. `man procfs` will point out the fields.

These are the amount of time spent in user, nice, system, iowait, etc.

You need to read the data twice with a delay between the two reads, calculate the differences in the readings, divide by the time between the readings.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21543/get-cpu-utilization-stats-from-c-program